# HTTP 204 error in REST (Dropwizard)

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I have problem with http 204 error. Always, when I try to use a POST command, and push data into dropwizard, I have 204. I don't know why, I tried solve it but code looks like okey.

```
public class POIDefinition {
  //  int id;
    String description;
   // String location;

}
public class poisDAO implements poiDAO {

    private static List<POIDefinition> POI = new ArrayList<POIDefinition>();

    @Override
    public void addPOI(String description) {
        POIDefinition newPoi = new POIDefinition();
      //  newPoi.id = id;
        newPoi.description = description;
      //  newPoi.location = location;

        POI.add(newPoi);

    }

    @Override
    public List<POIDefinition> GetAllPois() {
        return (ArrayList<POIDefinition>) POI;
    }

    @Override
    public POIDefinition retrievePOI(int id) {
        return POI.get(id);
    }


    @Override
    public void updatePOI(POIDefinition pd) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removePOI(int id) {
        POI.remove(id);
    }
}

@Path("/poi")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class POIResource {
    poiDAO pDAO;


    public POIResource(poiDAO pDAO)
    {
        this.pDAO = pDAO;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("add")
    public void addPOI(@QueryParam("addPOI") String description)
    {
        pDAO.addPOI(description);
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/getAllPois")
    public List<POIDefinition> getAllPois()
    {
        return pDAO.GetAllPois();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getPOI")
    public POIDefinition retreivePoi(@QueryParam("id") int id)
    {
        return pDAO.retrievePOI(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/removePOI")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void removePoi(@QueryParam("removePOI") int id)
    {
        pDAO.removePOI(id);
    }
}
```

I have track
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  -  [27/lut/2015:22:47:37 +0000] "POST /poi/add/?addPOI=test HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36" 1

Few lines code ago, I tried to create class with more objects like id and locations, but I don't know how can I add this data in rest-post command in one line, always I have the same error.

Comment: HTTP status code number 204 means that "The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content. Usually used as a response to a successful delete request." By calling which operation are you getting this behavior? Adding new elements?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add new elements. Actually, I'm trying to add only description of POI object and after show it in getPOI command

Comment: Then it makes sense that the application responded with something like "OK, I added it" when you tell it to add an element, just like it's behaving. I'd expect it to be added to the list, without returning the object I just added. Retrieving it for reporting is another, completely independent operation.

Comment: You're right. I made mistake :)

Comment: Cool. Then I'll quote myself and add this brief explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

204 is not an error, it means the request was successfully processed and the web service didn't return any other content in the body of the response.

Check [W3C page explaining status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code number 204 means that "The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content. Usually used as a response to a successful delete request."

It makes sense that the application responded with something like "OK, I added it" when you tell it to add an element, just like it's behaving. I'd expect it to be added to the list, without returning the object I just added. Retrieving it for reporting is another, completely independent operation.